# What makes `curl http://localhost:8000/initdb` return `init database` and `curl http://localhost:8000/widget` return 404?

Tags: database, docker, curl, localhost

I'm following the tutorial in [Use containers for development#Get and run the sample application  | Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/develop/#get-and-run-the-sample-application). At step 6, instead of getting an empty `[]` JSON string, I get:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/initdb
init database

curl http://localhost:8000/widget
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Why is that? Here is the result of `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
2a87fc863140   python-docker-dev   "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   6 minutes ago    Up 6 minutes    0.0.0.0:8000->5000/tcp   rest-server
7d7eb37dc40e   postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code [here](https://github.com/docker/python-docker-dev/blob/main/app.py), you can see that it sets up three endpoints: `/`, `/initdb` and `/widgets`. Those are the only *routes* that the app responds to.

You're trying to access `/widget` (without the 's' at the end) and so you get a 404 Not Found.

Try

```
curl http://localhost:8000/widgets
```

instead.